# Dynamically create table skeleton using numRows and numCols

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble using a couple for-loops to dynamically create a table using JavaScript.

In this example, **numRows = 2** and **numCols = 6**.

My code:

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i ++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        var rowData = $('<td></td>').text('test');
        row.append(rowData);
    }
    table.append(row);
}
console.log(table);
```

The console output shows an empty table. There are no rows or cells ...just this:

[image]

How can I fix this logic so it correctly fills the table with 2 rows of 6 cells each? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `empTable`?

Comment: @Ryan oops -- missed that one when I was renaming everything. fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable in the nested loop from `i` to `j`, and logging the html, rather than the jQuery object. (Also, those closing tags aren't necessary.)

```
var table = $('<table>');
for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i ++) {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        var rowData = $('<td>').text('test');
        row.append(rowData);
    }
    table.append(row);
}
console.log(table.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

for script side

```
var container = $('#my-container'),
  table = $('<table>');
numRows= 3; 
numCols= 4;
for (var x = 0; x < numRows; x ++) {

  var tr = $('<tr>');
     for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {


    tr.append('<td>text</td>');

     }

  table.append(tr);


}

container.append(table);
console.log(table)
```

html

```
<div id="my-container"></div>
```

working example

```js
var container = $('#my-container'),
  table = $('<table>');
numRows= 2; 
numCols= 4;
for (var x = 0; x < numRows; x ++) {
  
  var tr = $('<tr>');
     for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {

    
    tr.append('<td>text</td>');
  
     }
  
  table.append(tr);


}

container.append(table);
console.log(table)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another counter variable for the columns side instead of reusing the `var i`.

Here is an example demo:

```js
var row = 2, col = 6;
var $table = $('<table/>');
$contents = []; // hold the generated rows
for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) { // loop for rows
    $tr = $('<tr/>');
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) { // loop for columns
        // append a td with text [row][col] in tr
        $tr.append($('<td/>', { text: '['+ (i+1) +'][' + (j+1) + ']' }));
    }
    $contents.push($tr); // push each generated row to contents
}
$table.append($contents); // append the contents to table
$('body').append($table); // append table in body
console.log($table.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```